# Motion of prefabs on the circle with same starting position but different speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a code to instantiate GameObject into the list

```
public GameObject prefab = null;

void Start()
{
  List<GameObject> _list = new List<GameObject>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    GameObject thisObject = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
    _list.Add(thisObject);
  }
}
```

I want to use prefabs from the given list and use it as follows (motion on the circle with same starting position but different speed) :

```
void Update()
{
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
      _list[i].transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(i * Time.deltaTime),Mathf.Sin(i * Time.deltaTime),0);
     }
 }
```

but there is an error message: "The name '_list' doesn't exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

_list is a local variable in your Start method.
You have to declare a member.

```
public GameObject prefab = null;
public readonly List<GameObject> _list = new List<GameObject>();

void Start()
{
  _list.Clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    GameObject thisObject = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
    _list.Add(thisObject);
  }
}
```